# Splitting mainwindow.cpp into separate widgets with UI access

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qwidget

Currently I have a `mainwindow.cpp` that is getting quite large. There isn't an immediate necessity to refactor this file; this is just for readability's sake.

The current design of my project has multiple pages all combined into one `stackedWidget` class that each handle their own functionality.  As far as I know, I can promote the individual widgets of the `stackedWidget` in Qt Designer to their own custom widget, which I believe is what I should be doing in this case.

My issue comes into play when considering the `Ui` component of the `mainwindow.cpp` and how I can access it from the sub-classes.

For example, one of the pages is the `home_page`, and I promote it to a `homePage` class in Qt Designer with the corresponding `homepage.h`.

Here are the relevant files (trimmed for readability):

`on_start_button_clicked()` seems to be automatically linked to the slot via the `ui_mainwindow.h` without the need for `connect()` from what I can tell, but I want to be able to move it from `mainwindow.cpp` to `homepage.cpp`.

I also want to be able to access `MainWindow`'s `ui` pointer to adjust all of the `mainwindow`'s UI features (text setting, pixmap changing, etc.) as you can see in `mainwindow.cpp`'s definition for `on_start_button_clicked()`.

`start_button` is created in Qt Designer.

homepage.h

```
#ifndef HOMEPAGE_H
#define HOMEPAGE_H

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QString>

class homePage : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    private:
        MainWindow main;
    public:
        homePage(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    private slots:
        void on_start_button_clicked();
};

#endif // HOMEPAGE_H
```

homepage.cpp

```
#include "homepage.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

homePage::homePage(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    //not sure what to put here
    MainWindow main;
}

void homePage::on_start_button_clicked(){
    //Perhaps something like this?
    main->ui->start_button->setText(QString::fromStdString("Go!"));
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QString>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_start_button_clicked();

public:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_start_button_clicked(){
    ui->start_button->setText(QString::fromStdString("Go!"));
}
```

UI hierarchy in Qt Designer:

[image: Screenshot of the UI hierarchy in Qt Designer]

Comment: Why is there a `MainWindow main;` automatic storage instance inside a `homePage` constructor? Why do you promote `QWidget` (I guess?) to `homePage`? What is the additional functionality that `homePage` class offers? If my guess is correct, and `homePage` is supposed to be customized widget with some buttons, logic etc ... , then what is the problem you are trying to solve? `start_button` is a child of `homePage`, so it's accessible from within that class UI.

Comment: Ops, disregard my last sentence about "(...) accessible from within that class UI". One UI design in the QtDesigner == one `xxx.ui` and one autogenerated UI-like class. So yeah you have all of your elements from the screenshot available in your `Ui::MainWindow`. If you would like to create another `QWidget` with it's own design, create another QtDesigner project. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: As part or breaking up your monolithic UI widget into multiple widgets, you must also replace access to UI elements in different tabs with signal/slot combinations such that each widget is independent. The purpose of the mainwindow is then to connect the appropriate signals to the appropriate slots (in different widgets)

Comment: @Botje 's idea worked! I was able to successfully connect a subclass function to the mainwindow and have it called on button click.  I also created a getter function in homePage to receive a pointer to the mainwindow to access any of the ui/mainwindow parameters that I need to.  Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: In qt every object can have a parent object. That seems like the most logical way to access the main window.

Comment: Furthermore, if you only need access for some "parameters" consider splitting off these parameters to a separate "shared state" object. It can also be a QObject with its own signals and slots.